# Reallocate memory to avoid memory fragmentation

Tags: c++, memory, dynamic-memory-allocation, realloc, heap-fragmentation

Here is a simple example to explain the issue (with c++) :

```
A* a1 = new A;
A* a2 = new A;
A* a3 = new A;
delete(a2);
B* b = new B;
.
.
.
```

let's say the size of an `A` object is 3,
and the size of a `B` object is 4,
and the size of my heap is 12,
after deleting a2, the memory will be like this :

XXX---XXX---

I can't create a the object `B* b` even if there is enough memory, since it's not contiguous.

Just a simple example of memory fragmentation.

Can I avoid this dynamically by creating some kind of `reallocate()` function,
a function that would "move" the memory of object `a3` and put it right after a :

XXXXXX------

The function should obviously be called after deleting `a2`, so maybe reimplemeting `deallocate()` or `delete()` can do this, how can I do this please ?

This is just a very simple example to show the kind of problem i am dealing with

Comment: Let your OS take care of memory fragmentation.  Don't try and second guess it.  If you really want to do something, create a std::vector and use that.  You can use another vector of int to store indices of "deleted" objects.

Comment: This is just a simple example, I'm actually working on a very big project

Comment: First you need to prove that fragmentation is a problem for your software.  Once you've done that if you don't like the allocation/reallocation strategy of the OS, you can make your own.  What I wouldn't do is try to hack the OS memory manager around for your project.

Comment: Can you give me a simple example of how I could change the allocation/reallocation strategy ?? and how can someone hack the OS memory manager ?? ( I may have to do this, I am just a trainee in this project, there is many experts that would help me)

Comment: In this case create your objects in an array or vector so they are placed in one memory block.

Comment: As I said, this was just a simple example to show the issue, I can't just place all the objects in one vector, the project is like 10M lines ...

Comment: I agree with the above comments but I imagine that copying the contents of a3 to a local store, deleting and making a new a3 _might_ make a difference. Remember that the decisions of where to allocate memory isn't simple - read about flash memory wear levelling for example.

Answer (score 1):

Memory allocation is indeed often a bottleneck. But writing your own allocator is not easy. There are multiple ways of doing it wrong.

In your case it looks like some kind of [slab allocator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slab_allocation) would fit your need.

But instead of writing your own, you may choose to rely on a battle-hardened implementation like [jemalloc](http://www.canonware.com/jemalloc/). Facebook uses it with C and C++ and even contributed patches. See this [facebook engineering blog post](https://www.facebook.com/notes/facebook-engineering/scalable-memory-allocation-using-jemalloc/480222803919).

The question *how to integrate jemalloc with c++* is handled [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9521226/c-stl-with-jemalloc)

PS: I don't quote facebook because it is hype, but because it is a well known company with real performance issues. Google also uses a custom allocator: [tcmalloc](https://code.google.com/p/gperftools/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, do you know any tutorial for writing my own allocator ? It is a research project, so I may have to write my own allocator